# How to put temporary cell between cells in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I did newsfeed like instagram and I want to put a view inside posts temporarily like suggestion for you view inside posts on instagram.

I am confused how to put it inside reusable cells. Because I don't want to make this cell reusable.

[image]

Comment: "Because I don't want to make this cell reusable." WHY?

Comment: Because i see this cell when scroll like 600 pt again.

Comment: Create 2 prototype cells. One for regular feed and another one for suggestions.

Comment: "Because i see this cell when scroll like 600 pt again. " You clearly misunderstood the Reuse/Dequeue. And it's up to you to insert the model into your array and tell when to use it or not.

Comment: Thank you. @Larme i understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want want to make it reusable, Initialise(init) it every time. But that is not recommended way.

Instead of that, refresh data every time